# Little oh notation question stuck on the limit

Tags: limits, analysis, asymptotics

I want to prove that $$\ln(\sin(x))=o(\ln^2(x))  (x\rightarrow\infty) $$
And i start with the definition of little oh.
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{\ln(\sin(x))}{\ln^2(x)}\right)=0$$
I don't know how find that the limit above is equal to zero as x goes to infinty.

Comment: Oh, thanks you.

Comment: Unless $x$ is constrained in some non-obvious way, this isn't true.

Comment: But how when i write it on the calculator it gave me the answer is zero?!

Comment: Do you believe everything the calculator tells you? :-) ¶ More seriously, we don't really know what heuristics the calculator is using, so the conclusions it comes to are hard to assess.  My guess is that it recognizes the fact that $\sin x$ is bounded between $-1$ and $1$, and doesn't change behavior as $x$ increases, while $\ln x$ (and therefore $(\ln x)^2$) increases without bound, so it "guesses" that the ratio goes to $0$ as $x$ tends to infinity.  In this case, that guess is without merit, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pick the sequence of $x$ where $\sin x = 0$, you see the limit can't possibly exist. Also, remember $\sin x$ takes on negative values, and there the logarithm isn't even defined.

Comment: But when i tried to solve it by a  limit calculator on google it gave me a zero without a way to solve.

Comment: And when i draw it on the desmos it seems the function goes to zero when x aproaches infty

Comment: @SaraKanan: Yes, but it continues to have values arbitrarily far away from $0$ no matter how large $x$ is.

Comment: So, the question is not true?!

Comment: @SaraKanan, yes, the question is wrong.